# Gnus fails to connect to GMail AUTHENTICATIONFAILED

Tags: gnus, email

1. How can I debug what exactly is being sent and where?
2. The account I'm trying to connect has "two-step" authorization enabled.  However, I've checked that IMAP access is enabled and that "less secure" applications are allowed to access my account.

I thought, that if two-step authentication was a problem, I should be seeing a different error message, however, what I see is:

> nnimap (gmail) open error: 'NO (AUTHENTICATIONFAILED) Invalid credentials (Failure)'.

I'm absolutely sure that the details I provided in `~/.authinfo.gpg` are correct.

My `nnimap` settings:

```
(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "gmail"
               (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
               (nnimap-server-port 993)
               (nnimap-stream ssl)
               (nnir-search-engine imap)))
```

---

I'm able to connect with same configuration to another GMail account (by changing the details in `~/.authinfo.gpg`).

Comment: is this helping?: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17626/getting-gnus-working-on-windows-with-gmail

Comment: Have you tried setting `auth-sources '("~/.authinfo.gpg")`? Did you try with an ordinary .authinfo (without encryption)?

Comment: @jue the article hinted at the way one needs to set up double authentication with Google, which I tried, but either it doesn't work, or I don't understand how to use it, or my company's administrator had somehow prevented me from doing it. As for the other question: `.authinfo.gpg` works fine. If I change the information there so that instead of accessing company's provided account, I access my personal GMail account it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need generate a password for your application only (Gnus, in this case).

See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

I finished setup for Gnus in 1 minute, even though I never use 2 step verification for Gmail before.

1. Enable 2 step verification, I did a quick search and went to https://myaccount.google.com/security. Just follow its step by step guide and submit the form
2. In order to setup Gmail app password, I googled the keyword and went to https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en. Click the link "How to generate an App password", read the guide and click the link inside it. Login in with your google account
3. There is a "App" section inside dashboard, you can not miss it. Follow the guide.

I don't know what's your Gnus setup. To be honest, your question lacks the essential information. See https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/gnus-guide-en.org on how to setup Gnus.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I had a feeling this might be it... Sasha Chua also wrote she did this. But, the help article doesn't explain how to do this. Would you care to explain? When I try following the link in this "article" it says "The setting you are looking for is not available for your account."

Comment: @wvxvw are you a Google Apps customer, or is this a regular Gmail account?  In case of the former, you have to enable the feature in your domain control panel.

Comment: OK, I figured out finally what was going on. My company that used GMail service required that all employees use two-step verification. But, somehow, I've never created a second password, so my GMail account was in the limbo: I didn't have second password, but it still believed that I must have one. I was able to log in because of some cookie-related confusion. Finally, the cookies expired and I had to create the second password. Once that was done, I could follow the procedure outlined in this reply.